# Suckless's st messes up UTF-8 sometimes

Tags: unicode, suckless-terminal, rust

I wrote an echo program in Rust (which can deal with UTF-8) and occasionally st seems to mess up the UTF-8 input. I've tried different terminal emulators, like alacritty and gnome-terminal and they work fine.

To reproduce this:

- Run this Rust code in st:

```rust
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    for line in std::io::stdin().lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        println!("{line}");
    }
}
```

- Input things like "Rückgängig", or other strings with non-english characters.

After a while the program should fail:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: InvalidData, message: "stream did not contain valid UTF-8" }', src/main.rs:5:25
```

Does anyone have an idea how this could be fixed or why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you perhaps press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> while typing those words?

Execute `cat`, type something with accented letters, press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> a few times (across at least one accented letter), and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Do you get the same thing echoed back? I don't.

It looks like `st` doesn't set the `IUTF8` flag. While it erases the entire letter on-screen, only the last byte of the UTF-8 sequence is erased from the kernel's cooked mode tty buffer.

The command `stty iutf8` should fix that, but the right place would be for `st` to do the corresponding `tcsetattr(<IUTF8>)` call if the encoding is UTF-8, as other terminal emulators do this.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case (running `stty` in st and gnome-terminal revealed the missing attribute). It would be cool to see a patch to st, but for now I'll just put the command in my shell source file. Thank you very much.